# JDeveloper 12c | IntegratedWebLogicServer | Error while building the default domain

Tags: weblogic, oracle12c, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I'm trying to run IntegratedWebLogicServer using JDeveloper Version 12.2.1.4.0, and I have the following message:

> ERROR:  An error occurred while building the default domain.

And the log shows:

```
BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2020-02-10 11:53:05

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\nauana.nonato\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\nauana.nonato\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\nauana.nonato\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.wlst.ScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.java:106)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DomainScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(DomainScriptRunnerImpl.java:146)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.createDomain(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:606)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.build(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:274)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder$1.run(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:225)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\nauana.nonato\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.needsEscaping(ProcessImpl.java:279)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.createCommandLine(ProcessImpl.java:202)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:436)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 9 more
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the following steps to fix this issues in 12.2.1.4

1. Go to Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\ide\bin folder.
2. Edit ide.conf file.
3. Under ***# Other OSGi configuration options for locating bundles and boot delegation*** section (or any other section) add the following line

```
AddVMOption  -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

4. Restart JDeveloper.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem as you. I am installing Oralce SOA Quick Start 12c version 12.1
Version JDK: javac 1.8.0_251
To solve this problem. You set parameters in enviroment:
-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true

good luck: ManhKM

Comment: How To Set the enviroment path for -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
I'm Facing the same issue please ?

Comment: Yes, nice to help you.

Comment: Dear Osfar: About ERROR: An error occurred while building the default domain. You can do step by step: Step 1: Open cmd with Run as Administrator.
Step 2: Set param environment.
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true